# Stop full organization data export google admin console

Tags: google-workspace, data-export

I have exported the data of my complete organization (multiple accounts) from my google admin console. I want to pause/stop the data export now. What are the options to do this?

[image: Image showing the current status of my data export in admin console]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience it is not possible. You need to [contact Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for them to assist you on cancelling the task on the backend (it usually takes from 24 to 72 hours).

As a workaround you could remove the admin roles from the admin account that started the export, or if it was you, you could just give super admin rights to another user and ask to be removed as super admin temporarily because that would cancel the data export according to the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458).

Once it is cancelled you can ask the other person to give your super admin rights back, but be aware that the Admin console can take from 24 to 48 hours to give you full access as super admin again.

> "If your Google Account loses super admin privileges while an export you started is running, the export is automatically canceled. No data is exported and other super admins receive an email notification that the export was unsuccessful".

Comment: Hi Lara. Thanks for the reply. Looks like the data export is finished and I have the archive in google cloud console. However, I am unable to delete it now. It keeps throwing error. Do you know the right way to delete it?